Enable multi tenant silent authentication in Copilot studio
I am stuck with a requirement where I need users from different client to login to Copilot but using Azure Active directory I am unable to achieve it , So I have chosen to go with Generic OAuth ,which works perfectly fine from Bot side but whenever I am trying to sign in to bot using Custom canvas (directline api) I am not able to do so .
if (activity.from && activity.from.role === 'bot' &&
    (resourceUri = getOAuthCardResourceUri(activity))) {
    exchangeTokenAsync(resourceUri).then(function (token) {
        if (token) {
            directLine.postActivity({
                type: 'invoke',
                name: 'signin/tokenExchange',
                value: {
                    id: activity.conversation.id,
                    connectionName: activity.attachments[0].content.connectionName,
                    token
                },
                "from": {
                    id: userId,
                    name: clientApplication.account.name,
                    role: "user"
                }
            }).subscribe(
                id => {
                    console.log(id)
                    if (id === 'retry') {
                        return next(action);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    return next(action);
                }
            );
            return;
        }
        else
            return next(action);
    });

So if you guys having any idea how to achieve the following , it will be helpful !

Could you please refer this and let us know if it helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/configure-sso-3p
